# How to update/extend inherited dictionary in a child class in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

I have some classes, like the ones presented in the dummy code below and I wish to create a `@property` in the `child2` class where I will extend/update the values that the attribute with the same name, `information`, has in the parent class.

```
class MyBaseClass:
    
    information ={}
    
    def show_information(self):
        print(self.information)
        
        
class Child1(MyBaseClass):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.information={"TOKEN":"true"}
        
class Child2(Child1):
    
    @property
    def information(self):
        _information = {"IP":198}
        _information.update(super().information)
        return _information
        
        
child2 = Child2()
child2.show_information()
```

I tried the code above but I get an error `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Comment: so how can I create a property in the child2 class in which I extend the original attribute?

Comment: `Child1.__init__` (when invoked via `Child2`) is not creating a new instance attribute; it's trying to invoke the nonexistent setter of of the property defined by `Child2`. (Never mind the fact that `Child1.__init__` otherwise creates an instance attribute that shadows the class attribute defined by `MyBaseClass`.)

Comment: @chepner thanks. But how can I achieve what I describe? Extend the original dictionary with new values?